# Multiple files creation in C with specific path

Tags: c, loops, file

I am working on something where I need to create multiple files say 10 files in a specific path. I achieved it by below code

```
int index = 0;
    char filename[6];

    while(index < 10) {
        sprintf(filename, "%s_%d", "data",index);
        FILE *fp = fopen (filename, "w");
        index++;
    }
```

Here variable filename is used as file name but this creates all 10 files in the root directory where my code is placed. I have to create files in different directory lets say Desktop

```
FILE *fp = fopen ("Desktop\filename", "w");
```

this creates only one file in desktop and if i loop the same with above snippet it creates 10 files of same name which indeed finally one file only.

```
  while(index < 10) {
        sprintf(filename, "%s_%d", "data",index);
        FILE *fp = fopen ("Desktop\filename", "w");
        index++;
    }
```

which creates 10 files with hardcoded filename i.e. it is not taking my filename variable value.

How to achieve this to create multiple files with specific directory ?

Comment: The \f is a "formfeed" character; either escape your escape (\\f) or switch to the proper path separator (/).

Comment: `"data_0"`  is too long for a `char filename[6]` - there is no place for zero terminating character. Prefer using `snprintf`. Also it's easier to write `for (index = 0; index < 10; index++) {`

Comment: okay @KamilCuk but actual problem is different how to add a variable to my directory path ?

Comment: @mevets if i use like "Desktop\\filename" in this case also variable value is not taken it is creating file with hard coded string, instead i need to append variable to my directory path string

Comment: `add a variable to my directory path ?` Just like you added the string `"data"` to your variable. `char superbigbuffer[2000]; snprintf(superbigbuffer, sizeof(superbigbuffer), "%s\\%s_%d", "the\\path\\to\\the\\file", "data", index)`. Or really just beacause the path and `data` is hardcoded, just put it inside the formatting string.

Comment: Thanks @KamilCuk It worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to achieve this to create multiple files with specific directory ?

Just prepend your directory path to the variable.

```
 char filename[2000];
 for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
      snprintf(filename, sizeof(filename), "Desktop\\filename\\data_%d", i);
      FILE *f = fopen(filename, "w");
      if (f != NULL) {
         fclose(f);
      }
 }
```